# What is the origin of the shloka sādhūnāṃ darśanaṃ puṇyaṃ

Tags: scripture, shloka, identification-request

Which scripture has the following shloka?

> साधूनां दर्शनं पुण्यं स्पर्शनं पापनाशनम् ।
>  संभाषणं कोटितीर्थं वन्दनं मोक्षदायकम् ॥
>
> sādhūnāṃ darśanaṃ puṇyaṃ sparśanaṃ pāpanāśanam ।
>  saṃbhāṣaṇaṃ koṭitīrthaṃ vandanaṃ mokṣadāyakam ॥

Answer (score 2):

It is chapter 12 verse 7 of Chanakya's Niti Shastra.  [Here](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_major_works/chANakyanItisort.html?lang=iast) it is in Sanskrit and [here](https://eislibrary.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/chanakya-nity.pdf) it is in English

> sādhūnāṃ darśanaṃ puṇyaṃ sparśanaṃ pāpanāśanam । 
>  saṃbhāṣaṇaṃ koṭitīrthaṃ vandanaṃ mokṣadāyakam ॥
>
> One indeed becomes blessed by having darshan of a devotee; for the devotee has the ability to purify immediately, whereas the sacred tirtha gives purity only after prolonged contact.

Meaning of Sanskrit words :

> Seeing sadhus is punya. Touching them destroys sins. Talking to them is equivalent to a crore pilgrimages (holy rivers). Prostrating them paves way to Moksha.

Comment: it is not the entire sloka. it has only sādhūnāṃ darśanaṃ puṇyaṃ

Comment: I think you should remove the English statement just under the Sanskrit verse. That translation is not even wrong.